# How to implement android L like snack bar for below 4.2?

Tags: android

I was going through the design guidelines of android L and found a very intuitive way of showing errors. Now I have started to implement it in my application but haven't found any help on the web.

[image]

I have tried to search about the implementation of this kind of pattern, but found a library like croutons.

Is there any existing controls in android L for showing the error given in above image or we have implement our own?

**EDIT**

**It is called SnackBar**

Comment: This feature is called **SnackBar**! I think Google not yet added this feature to SDK. Eventually they will for sure. But till then you can use library projects to implement snackbar into your application. Here is one for your [reference](https://github.com/MrEngineer13/SnackBar)

Comment: Thanks @KevinChris for the information. Will implement using the mentioned lib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google has released **design support library** that contains SnackBar support.

To implement SnackBar use the below given snippet

```
Snackbar
  .make(parentLayout, R.string.snackbar_text, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
  .setAction(R.string.snackbar_action, myOnClickListener)
  .show(); // Don’t forget to show!
```